# Submanifolds of oriented manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional oriented manifold. Let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Suppose $c$ is a regular value of $f$ with $f^{-1}(c)$ nonempty. Show that $f^{-1}(c)$ is an oriented regular submanifold of $M$.

By [constant rank thoerem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem), I know that $f^{-1}(c)$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional regular submafold of $M$, but how to show that it is orientable?

Comment: What definition of orientability are you using?

Comment: Note that $\forall p\in f^{-1}(c)$, the tangent space to the fibre is $T_{p}(f^{-1}(c)) = \text{Ker } df_p$. If $M$ was $\Bbb R^n$, then this tangent space would be $\langle \nabla f_p\rangle^{\perp}$ so the gradient of $f$ would give an orientation of $f^{-1}(c)$.

Comment: @florence The determinants of  the Jacobian of transition maps are positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is the manifold $f^{-1}(c)$. Prove that $\triangledown f$ is normal to $S$ in $M$. Now if $S$ is non-orientable then there exists a continuous  choice of collection of ordered basis at each point of $S$. Attach $\triangledown f$ with it. This will show that $M$ is non-orientable, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you define the gradient?

Comment: Use local charts. See the Riemannian manifolds section of gradient in Wiki page of gradient.